# Where is $HOME set in Centos 6.3

Tags: centos, shell, centos6

WHere is the $HOME environment variable set in Centos 6.3?

I've looked in:

- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/*
- /etc/bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bashrc

Also, the second to last column in /etc/passwd has the correct home directory.

SELinux is disabled, fwiw.

Comment: login program set it. see http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hllogin.html

Comment: Looking to set HOME for a non-tty login.  That link doesn't point to a script that's run, from what I saw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login programs set these variables. You can of course override HOME if you must, or even unset it -- but unless you went to effort to modify the source of each program you can not ever get rid of it.

Note even if you alter HOME to be something else the authoritative source of your home directory will always be present in `passwd` or the `nsswitch` derivative.

If you login via a real TTY, login will set it.

**From util-linux in login-utils/login.c**

```
setenv("HOME", pwd->pw_dir, 0); /* legal to override */
setenv("USER", pwd->pw_name, 1);
setenv("SHELL", pwd->pw_shell, 1);
setenv("TERM", termenv, 1);
```

If you login via SSH sshd will set it:

**From session.c in sshd**

```
child_set_env(&env, &envsize, "USER", pw->pw_name);
child_set_env(&env, &envsize, "LOGNAME", pw->pw_name);
child_set_env(&env, &envsize, "HOME", pw->pw_dir);
```

If you login via GDM it will set it in there.

**From gdm in daemon/gdm-session-worker.c**

```
gdm_session_worker_set_environment_variable (worker, "LOGNAME", worker->priv->username);
gdm_session_worker_set_environment_variable (worker, "USER", worker->priv->username);
gdm_session_worker_set_environment_variable (worker, "USERNAME", worker->priv->username);
gdm_session_worker_set_environment_variable (worker, "HOME", home);
gdm_session_worker_set_environment_variable (worker, "SHELL", shell);
```